# ¿Qué información contiene el archivo "/etc/group-" en Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

¿Qué contiene el archivo `/etc/group-`?

Nótese que me refiero a `/etc/group-`, con guion al final, no a `/etc/group`.

Comment: Es un archivo, no un directorio.

Answer (score 5):

`/etc/group-` es un backup de la anterior versión de `/etc/group`.

Hay otros ficheros que también se copian de la misma manera, como  `/etc/passwd-` y `/etc/shadow-`.

Todos los comandos de gestión de usuarios y grupos como `useradd, usermod, userdel, groupmod, groupdel` y demás crean/actualizan estos ficheros de backup después de ejecutar los comandos de forma exitosa.

<sub>Información extraída de [What is the purpose of `/etc/group-`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25575/40596) de Unix & Linux SE.</sub>

Comment: ¿Alguna razón para no usar la colita de chancho, como `/etc/group~`?

Comment: @CandidMoe ni idea, a mí también me extrañó.